# How can I install RDOC of gems already installed?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rdoc

I have some gems that don't have ri/rdoc files and I'd like to know if there is a way to install this rdoc files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you install documentation for existing gems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664651/can-you-install-documentation-for-existing-gems)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

[Some of the answers on this question may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202060/how-do-i-generate-rdoc-for-all-of-rails)

OLD:

[This site seems to have your answer.](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page95)

Example:

```
gem rdoc rake --version 0.5.4
```

Comment: I've tried but don't work.
when I use "gem server" rdoc file was not found

Comment: Check my edit. I found another stackoverflow page that may help you. Take a look at all of the answers.

Answer (score 5):

Just rerun (works for gem v1.8.23):

```
gem install your_gem_name --rdoc
```

Comment: I tried this and it looked like it worked (e.g. the rdoc option became clickable in the web page served up by gem server), however, clicking on it just resulted in an error page. As it turns out, I had --no-ri set because I don't use RI documentation, but apparently when you try to view RDOCs via gem server, they look for a cache.ri file and through an exception if they can't find it. .... So short story, if you're going to do this make sure you generate RI docs too .  gem install your_gem_name --rdoc --ri