# What documentation software is using Ruby on Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, rdoc

Some time ago I read the changelog of a Ruby on Rails version (I think 3.1.0). In that was written that the documentation "system"/"software" was changed. The current can be browsed [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).

*What is the new documentation software used by Rails? Where I can find that and the related documentation? How should I use that?*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  we're not customer support for the documentation authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[screenshot http://pix.am/AeJE.png](http://pix.am/AeJE.png)

This gives us a hint that it is made with [RDoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/). I thought, however, that they are using [YARD](http://yardoc.org/) now.

Answer (score 2):

They switched to [SDoc](https://github.com/voloko/sdoc) for version 3.1.  The announcement is here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/8/29/the-rails-api-switches-to-sdoc

This post provides good instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7463142/8179