# Downloading offline rails 5 docs and guides

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pls how do I get the offline version of rails 5.0.1 docs and guides?

I have tried this

> > rake doc:guides

But I got this error

> > rake aborted!
> >
> > Don't know how to build task 'doc:guides' (see --tasks)
> >
> > (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> `rake doc:guides` is not supported from Rails 5.0. [See this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd7cc5254b090ccbb84dcee4408a5acede25ef2a)

Using `rdoc` install docs of rails if not already.

```
gem install rails --rdoc
```

then run `$ gem server` and open http://localhost:8808 to view the gems and corresponding documentations. 
[image]

If doc is installed, the `rdoc` link will be active. Otherwise, just install the rdoc of the gems. [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202060/how-do-i-generate-rdoc-for-all-of-rails)

---

If you are in Linux system, you can use https://zealdocs.org/ to load offline doc of any library you choose.